# Instancing a webservice on VS 2012 for WP7

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, instance

I have a web service on C# that connects to my database but one thing that i notice is that you cant add a web service in vs2012 you only can add a service reference and i cant find a way to instance that.The methods that the webservice have is one for login where you inform a username and a password and its returns a string and another method that basicaly do a insert on a table.

Comment: What is the underlying platform for your webservice; wcf, plain asmx or REST? What type of project are you tryint to add the service too, a webform/MVC website?

Comment: My webservice is plain asmx and i am trying to add to a windows phone 7 app

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966846/windows-phone-7-call-asmx-web-service

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure, and I don't have in this machine the windows phone tools, but you can get to Add a Web Rereference from Add Service like this....and I don't have vs2012 either.... I'm using vs 2010

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It would be ideal to do that but in visual studio 2012 this option dont exist so what i have to do is to add as a regular service reference and instance that